What clue does Apollos 'knew only the baptism of John,' provide about his subsequent change and impact on the church after meeting Priscilla & Aquila?
Text: Acts 18: 24 -28 (ESV)

Now a Jew named Apollos, a native of Alexandria, came to Ephesus. He
was an eloquent man, competent in the Scriptures. He had been
instructed in the way of the Lord. And being fervent in spirit, he
spoke and taught accurately the things concerning Jesus, though he
knew only the baptism of John. He began to speak boldly in the
synagogue, but when Priscilla and Aquila heard him, they took him
aside and explained to him the way of God more accurately. And when
he wished to cross to Achaia, the brothers encouraged him and wrote to
the disciples to welcome him. When he arrived, he greatly helped those
who through grace had believed, for he powerfully refuted the Jews
in public, showing by the Scriptures that the Christ was Jesus.


I wish I knew exactly what you are asking here.

I suggest it would be better to focus on the text of Acts and what is actually conveyed by the narrative, rather than to theorise about what is not specifically recorded.

Edited the question to make it specific and short.

@Dieter -Thanks for editing. However, I would like to keep the original question, for I see there is something worth it for open discussion. The text already states what Apollo lacks.

@Sam, yes, but what you posted was hard to decipher as Dottard noted in  his comment. There's a lot to define here such as John's teachings and baptism, the prophecies being fulfilled about the Messiah, the fact that Jesus was the Messiah, what Jesus taught, his crucifixion and why he died, his resurrection, and the coming of the Holy Spirit. What did Apollos teach, what was incomplete, and how do you know for certain?

@Dieter - Thanks for your detailed insights. I agree there's a lot to unpack here. The meeting with Priscilla and Aquila likely filled in gaps regarding Jesus’s teachings, his role as the Messiah, his crucifixion and resurrection, and the coming of the Holy Spirit. By examining these aspects, we can better understand what Apollos was initially missing and how his teaching and impact on the church evolved after receiving more complete instruction. Luke’s contrast between John’s baptism and Jesus’s ministry provides a framework for this discussion.

@Dieter - Although details are absent in the text, the phrase 'knew only the baptism of John' is a specific technical term contrasting the ministries of John and Jesus. This deliberate choice by Luke, a competent scholar, highlights a notable change in Apollos, a very able man, before and after the meeting with Priscilla and Aquila. Together, we may find more exegetical clues in the text to understand this transformation better.

@Sam, Yes, exactly! The account also demonstrates the gentleness of Priscilla and Aquila compared to the modern behaviors and attitudes. They serve as role models for us.

The Clue It showed that there was more than one "baptism" that needed to be preached: the baptism John foretold, and the one Jesus demanded, and the one the Church experienced: the Baptism of the Holy Spirit! This is an important topic...don't close it.

Important Baptism(s) The baptism of John was a "baptism of repentance." (Matthew 3:1-11a, Luke 3:1-14) And Apollo did realize that John was a "forerunner of the Messiah". John recognized the Messiah as Jesus...the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world! (John 1:29-36)
But it seems from the reading of the scriptures that Apollo hadn't heard the second part of John the Baptist's sermons:

I baptize you with water for repentance. But after me will come one... who will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and with fire! (Matthew 3:11)


"I baptize you with water. But one more powerful than I will come, the thongs of whose sandals I am not worthy to untie. He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and with fire." (Luke 3:16)

Apollo was effective in mentally convincing his hearers of the fact that Jesus was the expected Messiah.  The one foretold by the prophets of old. But his preaching lacked a very important topic...a topic needed to empower the persecuted Christians to persevere. And a topic that would aid in convincing people to repent. It was a topic that Jesus considered quite important: the baptism of the Holy Spirit.

I tell you the truth (verily, verily, I say unto you),it is for your good that I am going away. Unless I go away, the Counselor (Comforter) will not come to you; but if I go, I will send Him to you.When He comes He will convict the world of guilt in regard to sin and righteousness and judgment...(John 16:7-8)


Do not leave Jerusalem, but wait for the gift my Father promised, which you have heard Me speak about. For John baptized with water, but in a few days you will be baptized with the Holy Spirit! (Acts 1:4-5)

Jesus emphasized this Baptism, along with the baptism of repentance. And the Apostle Peter explained the deep meaning of the Church's experiencing this baptism in his sermon on the Day of Pentecost. The outpouring of the Spirit validated all that the prophets said, and all that Jesus claimed to be. (Acts 2:1-36)
The disciples were "continually being filled as they spread the Gospel throughout the Roman Empire. (Acts 4:31)  And later Paul showed the importance of this charismatic aspect of Christianity when he taught on it when writing to the Corinthian church. (1 Corinthians 12-14)
Priscilla and Aquila Noticing the gap in Apollo's preaching---that left out what John, Jesus, and Paul emphasized---they informed Apollo of this dynamic aspect of Christianity! And no doubt, this added a greater dimension to his ministry. It added a supernatural dimension; not just an academic presentation of theology. His teaching---just like Paul's---was not just in word only, but in power! (1 Corinthians 2:4)
Effect and Impact With the addition of this charismatic dynamic, Apollo's ministry was enhanced, and the new believers were greatly empowered---just as Jesus taught! (Recall the dynamic of power the 72 experienced when Jesus sent them out!) The believers were not only converted to a religion, the were introduced to a living God whose power would be manifested in every day life...convicting...healing...saving...delivering, etc. (Mark 16:15-20)
Apollo's new insight would have been a blessing, not only to him, but to the Churches he ministered to...and to the new converts!
Addendum If Aquila and Pricilla witnessed pastors and evangelists today, in modernity, leaving out this important aspect of Christianity while they preached, would they also be prompted to confront these ministers, as well? And encouraged them to preach and inform congregations about the Baptism of Repentance AND the Baptism of the Holy Spirit?
How much of the dynamic of the Gospel is missing, that is readily available to empower the Church in today's challenges? Are there any Aquilas and Priscillas around today to bring correction?

@Sam - Does this answer adequately open the window to the necessity of Aquila being confronted? And wouldn't this new dimension of, not just teaching, but of experience in his life really add dynamic power to his ministry? It was the evangelism in the power of the Holy Spirit that "turned the world upside down"! Compare Paul saying that he "came, not in word only, but in power" (i.e. signs and wonders in Jesus name)!  The Early Church need this complete Gospel (In recent modern days it was called The Full Gospel.)  You asked a good insightful question.

Paul met and stayed with Aquila and Priscilla prior to them hearing Apollos speak.  Paul would have had ample time to share the "abundance" of "hidden mysteries" that Christ ascended had been revealing to Paul.  Apollos was not yet made aware of Paul's gospel of God's grace and Christ crucified, so Aquila and Priscilla were the first ones to simply give Apollos the now more complete gospel (good news) of Christ from Paul.
Knowing only the "baptism" of John indicates that prior to coming to the more "perfect" knowledge of the truth, Apollos was unaware of the Spirit now filling the believer at the moment of belief.
There now being one baptism, performed by the Spirit Himself and without the need of water, Apollos would be in better alignment with Paul's gospel to the church, the body of Christ, in his ministry going forward.
Ephesians 4:5

One Lord, one faith, one baptism,

Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Even Peter is now aware that it is not the type of baptism that merely washes the flesh that matters:
1 Peter 3:21

The like figure whereunto even baptism doth also now save us (not the putting away of the filth of the flesh, but the answer of a good conscience toward God,) by the resurrection of Jesus Christ:

Aquila and Priscilla would have basically told Apollos that the act of water baptism was no longer necessary.
Paul indicates that it diminishes the completeness we have been gifted through Christ crucified for us.
1 Corinthians 1:14-17

I thank God that I baptized none of you, but Crispus and Gaius;
15 Lest any should say that I had baptized in mine own name.
16 And I baptized also the household of Stephanas: besides, I know not whether I baptized any other.
17 For Christ sent me not to baptize, but to preach the gospel: not with wisdom of words, lest the cross of Christ should be made of none effect.

Paul was to be the new pattern for believers from his administration forward until the last believer fills the body of Christ.
1 Timothy 1:16

Howbeit for this cause I obtained mercy, that in me first Jesus Christ might shew forth all longsuffering, for a pattern to them which should hereafter believe on him to life everlasting.

Romans 11:25

For I would not, brethren, that ye should be ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits; that blindness in part is happened to Israel, until the fulness of the Gentiles be come in.

With 1) Paul being the first member of the church, the body of Christ, 2) Paul not being sent to baptize, 3) there now being but one baptism (by the Spirit), 4) Paul being the pattern from hereafter him, Apollos would be certain that water baptism is now a thing of the past.
It is also interesting to consider the purpose in introducing Apollos in Acts, during the transition of Israel and the kingdom gospels to Paul's gospel of Christ crucified and regarding the church, the body of Christ.  Apollos only knew "the baptism of John".  This could indicate that he was not even aware of the fact that Messiah had come and gone, thus why Paul is able to make the statement that it is Christ's heavenly ministry to him that is now the latest message of Christ to follow.
1 Corinthians 4:15-16

For though ye have ten thousand instructers in Christ, yet have ye not many fathers: for in Christ Jesus I have begotten you through the gospel.
16 Wherefore I beseech you, be ye followers of me.

2 Corinthians 5:16-17

Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more.
17 Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

